# After 2 characters, split remaining characters into groups of 4 characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

How can you get say a number `99123412341234` to `99-1234-1234-1234`?

- First two characters are in a group (`99`).
- The rest are separated into groups of 4 characters (`1234, 1234, 1234`).
- The groups are joined with a `-`.

My frankenstein version works (see below), but **there must be a more elegant solution.**

```
let myNumber = 99123412341234;  

let parsedNumber = [
    myNumber.slice(0,2), 
    myNumber.slice(2, scannedTicket.ticketId.length).match(/.{1,4}/g).join("-")
].join("-");

// Result: parsedNumber = "99-1234-1234-1234"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update:

As per the comments, Lookbehind might not be supported by all browsers so here's a version that doesn't use Lookbehinds:

```js
const input = `99123412341234`;
const regex = /(?=(?:\d{4})+$)/gm;
const subst = `-`;

if (/^\d\d(?:\d{4})+$/.test(input))
{
    const result = input.replace(regex, subst);
    console.log(result);
}
```

This uses two patterns; one to check if the input string is in the correct format: `^\d\d(?:\d{4})+$`. And the other one to match and replace the split positions: `(?=(?:\d{4})+$)`.

---

### Original answer:

You may use the following pattern:

```
(?<=^\d\d(?:\d{4})*)(?!$)
```

And replace with `-`.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kFA1CF/1).

#### Breakdown:

```python
(?<=            # Start of a positive Lookbehind.
    ^           # Beginning of the string.
    \d\d        # Matches exactly two digits.
    (?:         # Start of a non-capturing group.
        \d{4}   # Matches exactly four digits.
    )           # End of the non-capturing group.
    *           # Repeat the previuos group between zero and unlimited times.
)               # End of the Lookbehind.
(?!$)           # Negative Lookahead to prevent matching the position at the end.
```

#### JavaScript example:

```js
const input = `99123412341234`;
const regex = /(?<=^\d\d(?:\d{4})*)(?!$)/gm;
const subst = `-`;

const result = input.replace(regex, subst);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Lookbehind is not supported in many browsers, for example with Firefox I get: `"message": "SyntaxError: invalid regexp group",`

Comment: @Toto Thanks! Added another solution that doesn't require Lookbehinds.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without a for-loop by reducing every character onto a sub-array and then joining the results.

```js
console.log(formatNumber(99123412341234, '-', 4, 2));

/**
 * Formats 
 * @param {int}    n - a number
 * @param {String} d - delimiter
 * @param {int}    p - partition size
 * @param {int}    o - initial offset
 */
function formatNumber(n, d, p, o) {
  return n.toString(10).split('').reduce((a, c, i) => {
    if (i % p === o) a.push([c]);
    else a[a.length - 1].push(c);
    return a;
  }, [[]]).map(e => e.join('')).join(d);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Of course, if you want a regular expression version you can try this...

```js
console.log(formatNumber(99123412341234, '-'));

function formatNumber(n, d) {
  return n.toString(10).match(/^(\d{2})(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d{4})$/).slice(1).join(d);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: You can use replace as well, `n.toString(10).replace(/^(\d{2})(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d{4})$/, (_, g1, g2, g3)=> g1 + '-' + g2 + '- '+ g3)`

Comment: @CodeManiac I was being sly by returning a slice of the matching groups instead. :)

Answer (score 1):

`/(\d){4}/g` regex here will match any digit (`\d`) in groups of 4 (`{4}`), for the entire string (`/g`)

```js
function formatNumber (input) {
  let a = input.slice(0, 2);
  let b = input.slice(2).match(/(\d){4}/g).join('-')
  
  return `${a}-${b}`
}

console.log(formatNumber("99381938999314"))
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

```js
let number = 99123412341234;
number = number.toString(); // Convert number to string.

let parsedNumber = number.slice(0, 2); // Get first two characters.
let length = number.slice(2).length;

for (let i = 2; i < length; i += 4) {
  parsedNumber += "-" + number.slice(i, i + 4);
}

console.log(parsedNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>  num = `35410009667444306`
'35410009667444306'
> `${num.substr(0, 2)}-${num.slice(2).match(/.{1,4}/g).join(`-`)}`
'35-4100-0966-7444-306'
```